# Error 0xc0000017 when trying to install windows 10 on brand new computer

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod, windows-installation, windows-installer

Installing windows on a brand new computer (HP Notebook 15-dw2023nj i5-1035G1
8G 256G FD
Came with freedos only, was purchased that way).

When booting from USB flash drive in getting a bsod (after the HP logo):
An unexpected error has occurred
Error code 0xc0000017

And option to retry, see firmware setting, or startup settings.

Google and su searched yielded no relevant solutions.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What was installed on the computer when you purchased it?  Most likely Windows 10.  Does that start up (without trying to install anything?

Comment: @John Came only with freedos, no is installed, this is how I bought it. Not my first time installing windows on my own, never saw this issue.

Comment: Have you tried this>>>>https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-fix-error-code-0xc0000017/47a80565-40a4-4a98-bb1a-3b7d24851483

Comment: @Moab I cannot access command prompt as I can't install windows because of this error, this solution does not apply. Or you can explain how to open the command prompt from the bsod screen?

Comment: Can you make the Windows 10 ISO on a bootable USB Key? Then start with that, delete partitions, format the disk and install Windows that way. You can install Windows on a blank disk (I have done this) so what I describe should work.

Comment: @John I have windows on usb flash drive, when booting from it to install this is the error I get, like I said in the question

Comment: Hi Dor, you haven't told us the brand, model, spec or anything but from your description, I would guess the problem is that this computer is not [Windows hardware compatible](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/planning/windows-10-compatibility)

Comment: Ask HP Support if you can download a Windows 10 Recovery Key. There will be charge if the computer is not already licensed for Windows 10.

Comment: @RegEdit it's a brand new HP Notebook 15-dw2023nj i5-1035G1
8G 256G FD
Fully compatible

Comment: Make a fresh USB stick with Windows 10 2004. Make sure you are booting in UEFI mode. If you had FreeDOS then UEFI is either off or CSM is on. If you mean to dual boot with FreeDOS then leave CSM on, otherwise turn it off.

Comment: @DorMoshkovitz I'm facing the same exact issue with HP 15-dw2022np. Can't find relevant info online. Did you get to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use Rufus to created the bootable USB stick with ISO file. Download MediaCreationTool instead.("Download tool now" button).
https://www.microsoft.com/en-hk/software-download/windows10

1. Run MediaCreationTool.exe and Accept term.
2. Choose "Create installation media (USB flash drive, DVD, or ISO file) for another PC" and Next.
3. Choose "USB flash drive" and choose your USB drive
4. Finish.

Now your USB is bootable without 0xc0000017 error.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on a new HP 250 G7 laptop (it came also with free DOS).

I created the bootable USB stick with Rufus (latest version available on their site) and when trying to install, I got the same error.
Since the error means that it could be a hardware problem, I checked all the components using the HP utility that is present on the laptop. There were no errors. This pointed me to the conclusion that the error is a "Microsoft" style error (blame it on the memory when something is wrong).

Then I decided to try and install ubuntu 20.04 on it and flashed the same USB stick with the same version of Rufus (only ISO changed to the ubuntu one). Ubuntu installed in approximately 5 minutes and it worked perfectly (except Wi-Fi, but I did not bother to fix it, I wanted to see if the laptop works).

This got me thinking that the Windows ISO I was using previously is broken somehow.
I downloaded again the same ISO from the Microsoft site and performed checksum on both images, it proved that they are different.
I flashed the new image to the same USB stick with the same Rufus software.
This time the installation was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Error code 0xc0000017 is normally attributed to bad memory sections marked by Windows built in Boot Configuration Data which block the use of Random Access Memory (RAM) as a temporary store for data.

You should be able to recover and continue your installation by booting to the pre-installation environment from bootable media and following the steps provided by Microsoft:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-fix-error-code-0xc0000017/47a80565-40a4-4a98-bb1a-3b7d24851483

If this proves unsuccessful, the RAM in your new computer may be defective and you should have it checked and fixed under warranty.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the easiest solution is as it is quote by answered Feb 2, 2021 at 6:47 user_anonymous, download the latest Windows IOS from Microsoft website and make a bootable pen drive, then start booting from external usb by changing the UEFI boot order in the BIOS. 100% it will solve your problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).